# Android: How to get view in listfragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-listfragment

Hi i want to use this code, it is working in a onclick method because (View v) but how do i use this code somewhere else in a activity?

Here is the code

```
        ListView list= getListView();
        int position = list.getPositionForView(v);
        switch (position) {
        case 1:
                ImageView arrow = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.arrow);
                arrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
```

**So how to get the View v in this case?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? there's probably a better way of doing it.

Comment: @Buffalo Make an image visible only on the first list item (The list is not dynamic but it has static values).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I am not sure that this way is the best way, but works fine for me. After all Views are created, create listener  **onLayoutChangeListener** and put the logic you would like to implement for the item view at the specific position you want.

```html
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setOnLayoutChangeListener(getListView());

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}


private void setOnLayoutChangeListener(final ListView listview) {
    if (listview != null) {
 listview.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {

        changeFirstListItemView(listview);

    }
       });
    }
}

private void changeFirstListItemView(final ListView listview) {
   if (listview != null) {
 try {
    int listFirstPosition = 1;
    View view = listview.getChildAt(listFirstPosition);

    if (view != null) {
     setHiddenViewVisible(view);
    }

 } catch (Exception e) {
  // Print some debug info.
  String msg = "An error occurred while trying to set onFocusChange listener.";
  Log.e(TAG, msg, e);
 }
      }
   }

private void setHiddenButtonVisible(View listItem) {
    Button button = null;
 try {
    buttonId = R.id.listButton;
    button = (Button) listItem.findViewById(buttonId);
 } catch (Resources.NotFoundException nfe) {
           // Print some debug info.
 }

 if (button != null) {
    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           // Optional, add here button listener, or something else...
        }
}
```